# create web service rest with symfony2

Tags: rest, symfony

I want to create web services rest with Symfony2, I followed several tutorial,the documentation is not clear.
I need an easy tutorial to create web services rest with Symfony2. thank you

Comment: Care to add any details about the service you're planning? That might inform the recommendations you receive.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the easiest way create REST based on fosrestbundle follow docs.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html
Or If I were you I'd try use for rest api micro - framework that names silex.

http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/usage.html